# Can we extend this measure uniqueness theorem?

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ finite measures on $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B$ such that $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)$, and $\mathcal A$ an intersection stable generator of $\mathfrak B$ such that $\mu_1(A)=\mu_2(A)$ for all $A\in\mathcal A$. It is well known that above hypothesis implies $\mu_1=\mu_2$. Can we have the same conclusion if $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are totally finite signed measures? Thanks.

Comment: Do you still assume that $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)$? In this case why wouldn't the same argument work?

Comment: I drop that assumption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take $X$ an uncountable set, $\mathcal B$ the $\sigma$-algebra of countable sets and their complement, $\mathcal A$ the collection of countable subsets of $X$. Take $$\mu_1(A):=\begin{cases}0&\mbox{ if }A\mbox{ is countable},\\
1&\mbox{ if }X\setminus A\mbox{ is countable,}
\end{cases}$$
and $\mu_2:=2\mu_1$. $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are finite measures, and $\mu_2-\mu_1$ coincides with the $0$ measure on $\mathcal A$ but not on $\mathcal B$.

The main problem is that the measure don't have the same total mass. If we take $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)\in\Bbb R$, then we have $\mu_1=\mu_2$ by a similar argument than in the case of a finite non-negative measure.

Comment: I found this theorem in more than one papers: Let $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ be totally finite signed measures on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B$
of $\mathbb R^n$, and let $\mathcal A$ an intersection stable generator of $\mathfrak B$ such that $\mu_1(A)=\mu_2(A)$ for each set $A\in\mathcal A$. Then $\mu_1=\mu_2$.

Comment: If the generator contains $X$, no problem. But when it's not assumed  I think the counter-example works. Do they give a reference in the paper?

Comment: All of the books i read demand $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)$ for this theorem, it is needed to construct d-system for proof. This make me confuse.

Comment: If H1 is the hypothesis: $\mu_1(A)=\mu_2(A)$ for $A$ in an intersection stable generating collection and H2 the hypothesis $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)$, then (H1+H2) gives uniqueness, but not H1 alone.

Comment: There is no information about $X$ being element of $\mathcal A$. They refer the proof to Maß- und Integrationstheorie. 3., erweiterte Auflage by Jurgen Elstrodt and Measure and integral by Konrad Jacobs. Unfortunately, i can access none of them.

Comment: Maybe this question simplifies the problem: is there any intersection stable generator for Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B$ that doesn't contain $X$? As we know family of all open sets and family of all closed sets are intersection stable generator for Borel $\sigma$-algebra $\mathfrak B$, both contain $X$.

Comment: Ok i found one, collection of all compact subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: Maybe the fact $\mathfrak B$ being Borel $\sigma$-algebra guarantees $\mu_1(X)=\mu_2(X)$.